# Puppet Master and Puppet Server Confusion (What is the difference?)

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, puppet, passenger

I recently started learning puppet after I joined my organisation a month ago. My organisation uses puppet 3 and is in the phase of moving to puppet 4.

I am currently playing with puppet 3.8. Though the puppet documentation is nice I don't understand what is the difference between puppetserver and puppetmaster.

From this [link](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.8/reference/post_install.html) I understood that:
Puppet includes a basic puppet master web server, but you cannot use it for real-life loads. You must configure a production quality web server before you start managing your nodes with Puppet. 
Correct me if I am wrong this is the puppetserver service right ?
Isn't this powerful enough to serve like 400 servers ? 
Do we really need puppetmaster ( Apache/Passenger Puppet Master ) ?

Also from this [link](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.5/reference/deprecated_servers.html) I found that they have deprecated webserver. So can i skip learning the puppetmaster part as it will no longer be used ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple things going on at once here:

- The default Puppet Master running using WEBrick is the not
  production-ready service.
- The default Puppet Master running using
  Rack and Apache is the production-ready service.
- The Puppet Server is a newer project, designed to replace the default 
  Puppet Master, and is production-ready.

Comment: puppetserver uses jruby to use java jvm to execude the ruby code

Answer (score 2):

A very good explanation for the difference between puppet server and master has been provided on the official site itself.

https://docs.puppet.com/puppetserver/5.0/puppetserver_vs_passenger.html

The conclusion is, puppet-server is going to be the future and puppet master will be deprecated over the time.

Comment: The link is no longer available